# comma separated list of several table columns

Tags: t-sql

I am using this:

```
COALESCE(Col1, '') + COALESCE(', ' + Col2, '') ....
```

to combine several columns as a comma separated list. Unfortunately, this does not produce the expected results if, for example, Col1 is NULL. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this using [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) along with `COALESCE`

```
STUFF(COALESCE(', ' + Col1, '') + COALESCE(', ' + Col2, '') ....,1,1,'')....
```

`STUFF` will remove the first character i.e. `,`

Comment: I was aware of stuff thanks but usually used it to create comma separated list of rows with joins. Thanks.